# Different output is produced as a result of Java program when executed from windows

Tags: java, jar, bufferedwriter

I am running a Java program to compute all paths in a tree. When I run it form eclipse on windows as I see an output1, but when I run the same program from jar or Mac, I notice different output. There are lots of diffs. Even file sizes are different. Does buffer writer behave differently when depending on platform?

So, I have a same output when executed from the jar or executed on Mac Eclipse, but different output when executed from windows eclipse.

Here is the code thats writing to the file:
Member Variable:

```
    public  HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> nodeListFromFile = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

Funciton:
    public void getAllPaths(String root, String path){
        //Since we are assuming there are approximately 12-16 levels
        //And we are expecting a LCA in less than 16 steps
        //All paths evaluated are of max size of 16 using this counter
        int stepCounter = 0;
        File file = new File(outPutfilePath);

        try{
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }  


            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            //Iterate over each child node
            for(String childNode: nodeListFromFile.get(root)){
                String tempPath = path;
                if((tempPath.indexOf(childNode)  grandChildSet = nodeListFromFile.get(childNode);
                    boolean goodGrandChild = true;
                    for(String gc: grandChildSet){
                        if(!path.contains(gc))
                            goodGrandChild = false;
                    }

                    if(grandChildSet.size()==0 || goodGrandChild){
                        bw.write(tempPath+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                        bw.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            //End iteration of children
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally{
        }

    }//End of function
```

Comment: Edit Member variable:
 public  HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> nodeListFromFile = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

Comment: You can click on 'edit' to edit your question.

Comment: `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is different between mac and windows

Comment: Please provide examples of the outputs.

Comment: Sharing input and output files on my googledrive:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B68Fsbz5osGWZHg2ZGY0R19pTjA&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You use `line.separator`, which is **system dependent**.

- It is `\r\n` for Windows.
- It is `\r` for Mac.

Also (bit related),

- It is `\n` for OSX and Linux

So, you get different outputs.

Comment: I think its not just that. Im processing a tree with nearly 600,000 unique nodes. Output Im generating form Mac is some KB, while output from windows is in GB. Difference is that significant.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to define the "separator" is by

> File.separator

Example:

```
// Removing directories 
int lastDirectory = fileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
fileName = fileName.substring(lastDirectory+1);
```